# jQuery change contents of element

Tags: jquery

**Possible duplicate: [jquery change div text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103172/jquery-change-div-text)**

The above question is a possible duplicate, but I don't know why it doesn't work. I'm fairly new to jQuery as well.

Below is part of the function (all I have written right now). It's being triggered with an `onclick` event for an anchor tag.

```
function changeStatus(user)
{
    var esc = true;
    $.get('ajax/popupBase.html', user, function(data, stat, d) {
        $("#AjaxFrame").html(data);
    }, 'html');

    $.get('ajax/changeStatus.html', user, function(data, stat, d) {
        $("#PopupBody").html(data);
    }, 'html');

    $("#AjaxFrame").fadeIn('fast');
    $("#PopupTitle").html("Status Update");
    $("#Popup").center();
    popupState = 1;

    return esc;
}
```

Here is the template "popupBase.html" that I'm using with `$.get()`:

*Note: "popupBase.html" is a reproducible "popup" window that I have on this site and I can just insert data into the empty divs, and re-use html where possible*

```
<div id="Popup">
    <form id="Popup1" method="post">
        <div id="PopupTitle"></div>

        <div id="PopupBody"></div>

        <input class="button" id="Save" name="saveChanges" type="submit" value="OK" />
        <input class="button" id="Cancel" name="clearChanges" type="button" value="Cancel" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The `#AjaxFrame` is a container just outside all html on my site (inside `<body>`, outside `#Wrapper`). I also have two empty containers on my template from my `$.get()` call, called `#PopupTitle` and `#PopupBody`.

**Question:** Inserting the html retrieved from "changeStatus.html" into `#PopupBody` works fine, however, adding static text from `#PopupTitle` doesn't work. In [this possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1103191)'s answer, I tried using `.text()` to no avail.

**EDIT:** A note for future readers, I am clearing the contents of the `#AjaxFrame` after each use which *should* renew the ID usage.

Other things I've tried: clearing Chrome's cache (both latest and portableapp version) and checking for typos over and over.

I'm realllly confused about this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but it's not very clear to me what you want... What is not happening ?

Comment: Argh, sorry about that, I suppose I slipped the question into a paragraph without realizing it. Anyway, the issue I have is with `$("#PopupTitle").html("Status Update");` not changing the contents whereas, I can use `$("#AjaxFrame").html(data);` and `$("#PopupBody").html(data);` no problem. I really don't get it. :|

Comment: where and _how_ are you calling that function `changeStatus()`?

Comment: p.s. I doubt it's a case of duplicate ID's, but if someone can give me **solid** proof that it is, then alright.

Comment: @mmmshuddup - I'm using it, as stated in my question near the top, via `onclick` event for an anchor (`a`) tag.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it with Firebug or Chrome ? maybe there is an error above this line that is making it impossible to reach this code.

Comment: @Cfontes I have tried debugging in Chrome. Nothing on the console shows up.

Comment: @Zack could you provide de code + css + html in jsFiddle ? so we can run it and see ?

Comment: @Cfontes One step better: http://toro.azwestern.edu/~zbl/tssman3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your running into a race condition,  javascript isn't going to wait for those $.get functions to complete before running what happens after it.

If you want "Status Update"  to be in PopupTitle  AFTER your ajax gets have run their course, it has to go in the success handler

```
function changeStatus(user)
{
    var esc = true;
    $.get('ajax/popupBase.html', user, function(data, stat, d) {
        $("#AjaxFrame").html(data);
    }, 'html');

    $.get('ajax/changeStatus.html', user, function(data, stat, d) {
        $("#PopupBody").html(data);
        $("#PopupTitle").html("Status Update");   //will over write what is in data
    }, 'html');

    $("#AjaxFrame").fadeIn('fast');

    $("#Popup").center();
    popupState = 1;

    return esc;
}
```

Comment: Aha! Duely noted kind-person!

Comment: depending when you want AjaxFrame To actually fade in, and #PopUp to centre, you might need to move those as well :)  Glad i could help