# Change Div in content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to make my homepage so when the user click in the menu only the div in the content should change, and i should me change back again when the div a selected in the menu again..

http://thom239u.keaweb.dk/help/

i have tried with this:

```
function me(){
    $(".me").show();
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = $(".me");

}
```

but i won't work..?? i have tried replaceWith to but that delete the previous div.

Comment: see this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103172/jquery-change-div-text

Answer (score 1):

refactored it a bit, but this should work just fine if you want it as a function.

```
function me(){
    var $me = $(".me"),
        $content = $("#content"),
        meContent = $me.html();
    //$me.show(); // un-comment if you need it, useless unless .me is hidden
    $content.html(meContent);
}

me();
```

working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Z2Wk/1/

Comment: when i try this, and click, i won´t show anything ..
the .me is display: none;

but if i remove that it will not show the div i content after i click

Comment: remove the `//` before `$me.show();`. it's commented out, so it isn't running.

Comment: nothing is hiding the .me in my code, so it has to be somewhere in yours.

Answer (score 0):

After checking out your html, the absolutely easiest and the most ideal solution is to hide the unneeded divs, and show the needed one... So, the code for .me would be this:

```
$('#content > div').hide(); 
$('.me').show();
```

If you want to go a step further and make it nicer and more readable:

```
function showPage(class) {
    $('#content > div').hide(); 
    $('.'+class).fadeIn(200);
}
```

And then, your click function would look like this: `showPage("me")`... for home: `showPage("home")`, etc...

Comment: How come? It inserts the content of .me (which is empty), into #content.

Comment: the div .me has a height,width and a background color..
so i should just replace the .home div..

Comment: That's because there are CSS rules for the `me` class. The easiest way to make it work is to add the class to the #content div also.

Comment: Wait, just checked your html, you're doing it wrong... I'll update my answer.

Comment: Haha NIce..! so simpel! Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome! The problem with the original approach is that it was cleaning the #content div, thus deleting all the pages that are hidden inside (for some reason I expected the pages to be outside that div). Also, don't forget to select the answer that helped you the most, because that's how you the question will get marked as answered.