# Get div text element on change

Tags: jquery

```
  $('.val').text().change(function(){ /*Do something */ }); // something like this
```

Do something when div text is changed. How to get div text element?

Comment: How did you try to get it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery change div text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103172/jquery-change-div-text)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fire jQuery event on div change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can detect using `DOMSubtreeModified` event like this :

```
$('.val').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  alert('changed');
});
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M48rK/)

Comment: _Be very careful with this event it is easy to cause an infinite loop if you decide to change the DOM inside the event handler._

Comment: Works, thx :) sry for bad title, it's difficult to explain it or for duplicate, couldn't find it :/

Comment: @Jai please explain more about it what you are talking about

Comment: @EhsanSajjad its in the documentation @ [MDN here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified)