# How to show specific variable in jQuery from JSON REST-API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

After using the get method I am getting following JSON.

API link https://infocityonline.com/tennis/rest-api/?id=bitcoin

I want to show JSON id value in #id and symbol value in #symbol div.

Right now my code is just showing data in the console.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://infocityonline.com/tennis/rest-api/?id=bitcoin",
    "method": "GET",

}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);



});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="id">  </div>
    <div id="symbol ">  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin",
        "symbol": "btc",
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "image": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
        "current_price": 9409.45,
        "market_cap": 173153275856,
        "market_cap_rank": 1,
        "total_volume": 30609526190,
        "high_24h": 9582.42,
        "low_24h": 9350.51,
        "price_change_24h": -29.23718676,
        "price_change_percentage_24h": -0.30976,
        "market_cap_change_24h": -986277704.740356,
        "market_cap_change_percentage_24h": -0.56637,
        "circulating_supply": 18388787.0,
        "total_supply": 21000000.0,
        "ath": 19665.39,
        "ath_change_percentage": -52.07157,
        "ath_date": "2017-12-16T00:00:00.000Z",
        "atl": 67.81,
        "atl_change_percentage": 13799.79978,
        "atl_date": "2013-07-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "roi": null,
        "last_updated": "2020-05-29T18:15:23.854Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, so we can see were you are stuck.

Comment: This will place id in the div: `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = getResponse[0].id`

Comment: Well, of course it's only showing in the console, the only code you have in the callback is `console.log(response)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery change div text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103172/jquery-change-div-text)

Comment: Combine the above with [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
response = JSON.parse(response)
 document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = response[0].id;
document.getElementById('symbol').innerHTML = response[0].symbol
});
```

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/kishin-karra/pen/VwvoeLm

Comment: **Thanks** Its Working